# Accessibility (ADA) issue to read out timer in login credentials while entering

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

**Situation**: User has time limit say 15 seconds to enter the credentials, and user started typing credentials.

**Requirement**: ADA users has to be alerted with left over time frequently and also they should be allowed to enter the credentials

What is the best practice in this situation to read out timer and also focus back to input field without annoying them with reading out focus out and focus into input field

Answer (score 2):

[`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) is how you get text read by a screen reader without having to move the focus.  The focus can remain in the text field and your timer can still be announced.  But you'll still have some issues that as the user is typing, and the character they type is echoed by the screen reader, that will be intermixed with your timer announcement and might be confusing.

[WCAG 2.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-required-behaviors.html) talks about the user being able to adjust the timer so that's another thing to consider.